# How to transfer autocorrections from Word 2016 Windows to Word 2016 Mac?

Tags: windows, mac, microsoft-word

I have many autocorrections that I would like to transfer from Windows to Mac. I can't find clear information on where/if the ACL files can be transferred between operating systems. If not, is there an easy way to print out all autocorrect to be copied over manually?

Thanks